# HTML 5 and three.js code does not display anything on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, three.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>3d cylinder</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no,minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #f0f0f0;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="three.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="Stats.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script>

            var container, stats;

            var camera, scene, renderer;

            var cylinder;

            var targetRotation = 0;
            var targetRotationOnMouseDown = 0;

            var mouseX = 0;
            var mouseXOnMouseDown = 0;

            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            init();         

            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                var info = document.createElement( 'div' );
                info.style.position = 'absolute';
                info.style.top = '10px';
                info.style.width = '100%';
                info.style.textAlign = 'center';                
                container.appendChild( info );              

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
                camera.position.y = 150;
                camera.position.z = 500;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                // cylinder
                var materials = [];
                for ( var i = 0; i < 6; i ++ ) {

                    materials.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff } ) );

                }
                cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(100, 100, 400, 50, 50, false), materials);
                    cylinder.overdraw = true;
                    scene.add(cylinder);

                renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                stats = new Stats();
                stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
                container.appendChild( stats.domElement );   

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
                windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to draw 3d cylinder using HTML5 and three.js by following code. I am using Canvas rendering and testing it on google chrome browser. On console it is shwowing "Three.CanvasRenderer 50". What could be the reason and what does this message mean ?

Comment: Is it compulsory to add animation for a scene in three.js ?

Comment: No, but I think you need to call render at least once, as in: renderer.render( scene, camera );

Comment: I added `renderer.render( scene, camera );` at last in init() but still it does not work.

Comment: Is it like CylinderGeometry() works only on WebGL rendering ?

Comment: I want to create a 3d cylinder or polygon shape with high number of edges and entire shape look like a bending pipe.

Comment: Go back through some of your old questions and accept some answers, and people might be more willing to look into this for you.

Comment: Finally I've got a 3d textured cylinder with high number of edges on Canvas. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Try out one of the following "Hello world" examples:

[mrdoob.com](http://mrdoob.com/)

[Hello worlds](http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the initialisation of materials. Looks like you are attempting to map multiple materials onto the cylinder. Perhaps you took this snippet from a cube example:

```
var materials = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < 6; i ++ ) {
    materials.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff } ) );
}
```

The '6' in question is suitable for cubes, but incorrect for cylinders. I'm not entirely sure of the array structure for a cylinder, but I assume 6 is not the correct number of materials for a cylinder created with 2500 (50x50) faces. You will have to research the cylinder material format.
[Here is a discussion on github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/901) to get you started.

By doing this:

```
cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(100, 100, 400, 10, 10, false), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff } ));
cylinder.overdraw = true;
scene.add(cylinder);
```

you should see your cylinder.

Note you should also add the camera to the scene:

```
scene.add( camera );
```